# Why is "To prove P, assume ∼P and arrive at a false statement, which would make P true" an inaccurate description of proof by contradicition?

Tags: proof-explanation

I have a quiz with the following question:

> **Which of the following describes proof by contradiction?**
>
> D) To prove P, assume that ∼P is true and arrive at a false statement, thus proving ∼P would also be false, which would make P true.

D) isn't the correct answer, but I can't see why. Could someone explain what's wrong with this description?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit: Full question**

E), "None of the above" was correct.

[image]

Comment: You should put the other options up.  There may be a better answer

Comment: @JasonM The correct answer was "None of the above". But I've added the full question.

Comment: I think this assure that ~$P$ can't happen, but this not show that $P$ must happen

Comment: I have two guesses: 1) This quiz is being extremely nitpicky, and instead of arriving at a *false* statement, you have to arrive at a statement *you know to be false* 2) There are several slight variations of the method of proof by contradiction, and the quiz insists on following one of those to the letter. In one of the variations, you assume ~P, and arrive at both Q and ~Q (for some Q), in another one of the variations, you assume ~P, and arrive at P.

Comment: To prove $P \implies Q$ by contradiction, you would need to assume both $P$ and $\lnot Q$, then arrive at a contradiction (neither of the first two choices do that). I still don't see anything wrong with your choice.

Comment: The correct answer should be of the form "To prove $P \implies Q$, assume $ \sim P$ and $Q$, and arrive at a false statement, thus proving $\sim P$ does not imply $Q$, so $P \implies Q$

Comment: @JasonM: Why is that? Proof by contradiction isn't limited to proving statements of the form $P \implies Q$?

Comment: @joriki True, but most statements can be phrased as an implication

Comment: In my view, D describes proof by contradiction perfectly. Whoever set this question doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @joriki I'm just throwing out ideas for why D) could be wrong.

Comment: The only improvement to D that I can think of is replacing "false statement" with "statement incompatible with ~$P$". But I still think the question is stupid.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone. I just wanted to see if I was missing something. I'll ask my professor on tuesday and report back here what the logic was.

Comment: D. is certainly the best answer of A through D, and I don't see anything wrong with it as a characterization of proof by contradiction. If E is supposedly correct then it's a "trick" question, too nitpicky for its own good (or for yours). If $\bot$ is a falsehood, then $(\neg P \to \bot) \to P$ is a tautology. If you "assume that $\neg P$ is true and arrive at a false statement" [e.g. $\bot$], then you have proved $(\neg P \to \bot)$, so by modus ponens, $P$.

Comment: I have changed my mind: E is correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having panned the question in the comments, I have come to realise that D is in fact wrong. Let's consider a classic proof by contradiction: the infinitude of the primes. Let $P$ be the statement "There are an infinite number of primes." So we start by assuming ~$P$: there are a finite number of primes.

Now we say, OK, then there are $n$ primes for some $n$. And we use this assumption to prove that there are at least $n+1$ primes. But this is not a false statement! It is not even a statement incompatible with ~$P$, as I suggested in my second comment. It's more subtle than that.

So I retract my comments: E is the right answer.

Comment: Eh...in the case of the Euclid-style proof of the infinitude of primes there are some tricky matters with quantifiers going on. You say "suppose there are finitely many primes; then there exists $n$ such that there are exactly $n$ primes; I now present a prime which is not one of these; thus there are in fact at least $n+1$ primes; this contradicts the *instantiated* statement that there are exactly $n$ primes".

Comment: Thus you assumed there was *some finite number* of primes and derived a contradiction from *that* (namely that there exists $n$ such that the set of primes has exactly $n$ elements and also more than $n$ elements).

Comment: @Ian: I don't see your point (and I don't know what you mean by an instantiated statement). What do you disagree with, exactly?

Comment: The aim is to prove there are infinitely many primes. So we first assume that there is some finite number of primes. Then we use *existential instantiation* to choose a number $n$ to be the total number of primes. Then we use existential instantiation again to obtain the set of all $n$ primes. Then we use Euclid's trick to obtain a new prime. So we have a contradiction: we have both the statement "there are exactly $n$ primes" and the statement "there are more than $n$ primes".

Comment: Now we have to propagate that contradiction back to our original assumption: we know now that "there are exactly $n$ primes" is false, but that didn't depend on which $n$ we picked, so now we know we can't existentially instantiate "there are finitely many primes", so that's false too. So here the false statement is not "there exist more than $n$ primes" but "there exist exactly $n$ primes and more than $n$ primes".

Comment: I think these comments just go to emphasise that the original multiple-choice question is extremely ill-judged.